# Difference between normal constructor and mutator? Java

Tags: java

I was just wondering what the difference between a normal constructor and a mutator was? They both seem to serve the same purpose - to assign private variables certain values. Is there a certain advantage to one in a particular situation? Thanks

Comment: By "mutator" do you mean "setter"?

Comment: (If so, the difference seems clear: one sets values at construction time, one sets them any time thereafter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences are:

- A constructor the private variables are assigned *as part of the process of creating a new object*.
- A constructor will typically assign multiple variables ... which a well-designed mutator probably wouldn't do.
- (As @irreputable reminds me), a constructor can (and must) assign values to "blank" `final` variables ... which is something that a mutator cannot do.

It is also worth noting that:

- a constructor *could* call mutators (e.g. setters) to do the assignments, and
- you could leave the variables uninitialized in the constructor and expect / require the code that `new`s the instance to *then* use a mutator to complete the initialization.

---

> So other than that, they serve the same purpose?

No.  The purpose of a constructor is to create a new object.  The purpose of a mutator is to change an existing object.

Comment: So other than that, they serve the same purpose?

Comment: @ChaseYuan No, not at all. Contructors construct. Mutators. mutate.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor can assign a `final` variable. A setter cannot.

A setter can have a more descriptive name, for example

```
new Foo(25);
vs
foo.setAge(25);
```